# Are openssl implementations of hash functions bit or byte oriented?

Tags: c, hash, openssl, cryptography

Everything is in the title. I can't find any info about this specific detail, and while I went to check the implementation (which I will post here, you can find it in the header md32_common.h), I couldn't really tell...

Here is the HASH_UPDATE function which is called by every hash function update function (i.e. MD5_Update(...))

```
int HASH_UPDATE(HASH_CTX *c, const void *data_, size_t len)
{
    const unsigned char *data = data_;
    unsigned char *p;
    HASH_LONG l;
    size_t n;

    if (len == 0)
        return 1;

    l = (c->Nl + (((HASH_LONG) len) << 3)) & 0xffffffffUL;
    /*
     * 95-05-24 eay Fixed a bug with the overflow handling, thanks to Wei     
     Dai
     * <weidai@eskimo.com> for pointing it out.
     */
    if (l < c->Nl)              /* overflow */
        c->Nh++;
    c->Nh += (HASH_LONG) (len >> 29); /* might cause compiler warning on
                                   * 16-bit */
    c->Nl = l;

    n = c->num;
    if (n != 0) {
        p = (unsigned char *)c->data;

        if (len >= HASH_CBLOCK || len + n >= HASH_CBLOCK) {
            memcpy(p + n, data, HASH_CBLOCK - n);
            HASH_BLOCK_DATA_ORDER(c, p, 1);
            n = HASH_CBLOCK - n;
            data += n;
            len -= n;
            c->num = 0;
            /*
             * We use memset rather than OPENSSL_cleanse() here 
               deliberately.
             * Using OPENSSL_cleanse() here could be a performance issue. 
               It
             * will get properly cleansed on finalisation so this isn't a
             * security problem.
             */
            memset(p, 0, HASH_CBLOCK); /* keep it zeroed */
        } else {
            memcpy(p + n, data, len);
            c->num += (unsigned int)len;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    n = len / HASH_CBLOCK;
    if (n > 0) {
        HASH_BLOCK_DATA_ORDER(c, data, n);
        n *= HASH_CBLOCK;
        data += n;
        len -= n;
    }

    if (len != 0) {
        p = (unsigned char *)c->data;
        c->num = (unsigned int)len;
        memcpy(p, data, len);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although hash functions like MD5 typically operate on bit streams, software implementations usually operate on bytes to avoid the speed penalties of bit shifting (and because data is normally processed in units of bytes or larger in any case). In the code you posted, the line

```
l = (c->Nl + (((HASH_LONG) len) << 3)) & 0xffffffffUL;
```

multiplies the `len` parameter by 8 (by shifting left 3 times) to convert the byte count into a bit count, so I think it's safe to say that this code uses bits internally, but expects to be passed a stream of bytes.